# How can i pass a variable from userform1 textfield dblclk event to userform2 and then dynamically pass data back to userform1 through cmdbutton click

Tags: vba

On userform1 I have a text field that when it is doubleclicked opens a "timebox" Userform 2. The user then can adjust the time and then either cancel or apply. Apply should fill in Userform1 Textbox with the selection from Userform2.

If it was once instance no problem but i'm trying to use the Userform 2 on 28 + fields and can't reference each one separately. I need to pass the textfield.name on Userform1 to give Userform2 the address in which to send the data. But its userform2 cmdbuttom - Apply.

I looked at ByVal and ByRef which seems to work when its a Sub but not when its a cmdbutton.

Userform1 > Field

```vb
Public Sub AgStart1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim fieldname As String
fieldname = UserForm1.AgStart1.Name

TimeForm1.Show

End Sub
```

UserForm2

```vb
Public Sub TimeApply1_Click()
Dim timeselect

timeselect = Me.txt_Hours.Value & ":" & Me.txt_Mins & " " & Me.txt_AmPm
'I need the value above to be sent back to the field that spawned the Userform2
TimeForm1.Hide
 
End Sub
```

OR a better way like activecell for user form fields

[Userform1 text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KOIk.png)
[Useform2 spawned from dblclk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Asw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

UserForm1

```vb
Public Sub AgStart1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    PopTime AgStart1
End Sub

Public Sub AgStart2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    PopTime AgStart2
End Sub
'etc etc

Sub PopTime(ctrl As Object)
    Dim frm As New TimeForm1
    Set frm.TheControl = ctrl 'pass the control to the second form
    frm.Show
End Sub
```

UserForm2

```vb
Public TheControl As Object

Public Sub TimeApply1_Click()
    'set the value of the passed control
    TheControl.Value = Me.txt_Hours.Value & ":" & Me.txt_Mins & " " & Me.txt_AmPm
    Me.Hide 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I've been racking my brain for 2 days. Follow up Question - As I'm still newer to VBA. I read somewhere that using public variables can impact the performance, does this fall into that category? btw PopTime for some reason made me laugh. I will look into that as well as expanding my understanding of Objects

Comment: There's no specific performance issue with public variables.  From a design perspective a Property Set would maybe be "cleaner" but not essential.